# "invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘graph_edge {aka struct Graph_Edge}’"

Tags: c, graph, types, malloc

I don't understand why I get this error I looked in other answers and I did everything right. In graph data I use "struct Graph_Edge" in "struct Graph_Node" before the definition of the struct Graph_Edge. And I use "struct Graph_Node" in "struct Graph_Edge". I'm not sure if this could be the cause and if it is I do not understand why.

Graph data:

```
#ifndef Graph_Structure
#define Graph_Structure

#include <stdbool.h>

struct Graph_Node{

    int id;
    char node_name[100];

    //bool path;

    struct Graph_Node* next;
    struct Graph_Edge* edge;

    //struct Graph_Node* next_edge;

    };

struct Graph_Egde{

    int src;
    int dst;

    bool path;

    struct Graph_Edge* next;
    struct Graph_Node* node; 

};  

typedef struct Graph_Node graph_node;
typedef struct Graph_Edge graph_edge;


#endif
```

insert method:

```
#include "graph.h"

...

void insert_edge(graph_edge** edge, graph_node* node, int src, int dst){

    graph_edge* temp = (graph_edge*)malloc(sizeof(graph_edge)); // the error is here

    temp->src = src; 
    temp->dst = dst;

    temp->node = node;

    temp->path = false; 

    temp->next = *edge;
    *edge = temp;
}
```

I get this kind of error inside insert_edge method in the malloc line.

Comment: Typo: `Graph_Egde`. Voting to close.

Comment: Does anyone know how to change the debounce time of my keyboard? I typetoofast and that's where I get all my typos...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I didn't understand can you explain better? I'm new to c language...

Comment: Your actual `struct` is called `struct Graph_Egde` (`g` and `d` are swapped). Your `typedef` refers to `struct Graph_Edge`. Since there is no `struct Graph_Edge` defined in your program, `typedef` is considered an incomplete type.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
struct Graph_Egde
```

should be

```
struct Graph_Edge
```

Comment: I see no difference between  "struct Graph_Egde" and "struct Graph_Edge"...

Comment: E-g-d-e or E-d-g-e. That's the point with typos: you often don't see them. (lysdexic?)

Comment: sorry guys my mistake... I didn't see it sorry for wasting your time thought it was a more complex mistake...